# how to get random friend, using unity Facebook SDK 6.2.1

Tags: facebook, random, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I try something like this but the request dialog will never appear. Any help?

```
var fql = "/fql?q=" + WWW.EscapeURL("SELECT uid, name FROM user WHERE uid IN ( SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me() ) ORDER BY rand() limit 20");
    FB.API(fql, Facebook.HttpMethod.GET, RandomCallback)


    private void RandomCallback(){
     if (result != null)                                                                                                        
        {                                                                                                                          
            var responseObject = Json.Deserialize(result.Text) as Dictionary<string, object>;                                      
            object obj = 0;                                                                                                        
            if (responseObject.TryGetValue ("cancelled", out obj))                                                                 
            {                                                                                                                      
                Util.Log("Request cancelled");                                                                                  
            }                                                                                                                      
            else if (responseObject.TryGetValue ("request", out obj))                                                              
            { 
                   Util.Log("Send request");    
              }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's possible with FQL, but FQL is deprecated anyway. A much easier solution that is future proof would be to use the Graph API. The following call will return the friends and  you can pick a random one on your own: `/me/friends`

Just in case you don't know, since v2.0 of the API you can only get friends who authorized your App too, for privacy reasons.